# Radio button checked using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to alert some stuffs when a radio button is checked but my code isn't working. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[@name='crkbrd']").change(function(){
        if ($("input[@name='crkbrd']:checked").val() == 'Upload')
           { alert("Upload Your Own Ad"); }
        else if ($("input[@name='crkbrd']:checked").val() == 'Edit')
            { alert("Edit Your Ad Here"); }
        else
          { alert("You haven't chosen anything"); }
    });

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="radio" id="rb1" name="crkbrd" value="Upload" /> Upload Your Own Ad<br />
    <input type="radio" id="rb2" name="crkbrd" value="Edit" /> Edit Your Ad Here
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@` in the name selectors. JQuery uses CSS selectors, which is in this format:
  • `elementselector[attribute=value]`

Use one of the following selectors instead:

```
input[name=crkbrd]
input[name="crkbrd"]
input[name='crkbrd']
```

You should have got this error message when you ran your code:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@name='crkbrd']
```

Comment: Seriously that was pathetic of me or maybe i was just feeling too lazy. Thanks very much though.